# Position by center point, rather than top-left point

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, css-position

Is it possible to tell the code to position by the center point of an element, rather than by the top-left point?
If my **parent** element has

```
width: 500px;
```

and my **child** element has

```
/*some width, for this example let's say it's 200px*/
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
```

one would assume that based on the `50%` positioning, the child element will be in the middle of the parent, leaving `150px` of free space on each side. However, it is not, since it is the top-left point of the child that goes to `50%` of the parent's width, therefore the whole child's width of `200px` goes to the right from there, leaving `250px` of free space on the left and only `50px` on the right.

So, my question is, how to achieve **center positioning**?

I found this solution:

```
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
```

but I don't like it because you need to edit it manually for each element's width - I would like something that works globally.

(For example, when I work in Adobe After Effects, I can set a position for an object and then set specific anchor point of that object that will be put to that position. If the canvas is `1280px` wide, you position an object to `640px` and you choose the center of the object to be your anchor point, then the whole object will be centered within the `1280px` wide canvas.)

I would imagine something like this in CSS:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
horizontal-anchor: center;
```

Similarly, `horizontal-anchor: right` would position the element by its right side, so the whole content would be to the left from the point of its parent's `50%` width.

And, the same would apply for `vertical-anchor`, you get it.

So, is something like this possible using **only CSS** (no scripting)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If the element must be absolutely positioned (so, `margin: 0 auto;` is of no use for centering), and scripting is out of the question, you could achieve this with CSS3 transforms.

```
.centered-block {
    width: 100px; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, 0); 
    position: absolute;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxN7F/) for some examples. The important parts: `left: 50%;` pushes block halfway across its parent (so its left side is on the 50% mark, as you mentioned). `transform: translate(-50%, 0);` pulls the block half it's *own* width back along the x-axis (ie. to the left), which will place it right in the center of the parent.

Comment: @kaboom1 user beware:  browser specific commands should be thoroughly tested.  The good news is that there are usually equivalent properties for each browser out there.

Comment: Good solution, but at least nowadays there *is* a certain amount of cross-browser compatibility; just add keys `-ms-transform` and `transform` with the same value.

Comment: This works vertically as well: `.middle-block { height: 100px; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); position: absolute; }` The `top` rule positions the top of the element according to it's nearest relatively positioned wrapper, while the `transform` moves the element in accordance with it's own length.

Comment: Thank you for this solution

Comment: Thank You And also use transform: translate(50%,0) for RTL websites

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to center a text element in the middle of the container (using a header as an example

CSS:

```
.header {
     text-align: center;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     position: absolute;
}
```

It centers by a middle anchor point.

Answer (score 2):

If adding another element is an option, consider the following:

```css
/* CSS for all objects */

div.object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%; /* to anchor at the top center point (as opposed to true center) set this to 0 or remove it all together */
}

div.anchor {
  position: absolute; /* (or relative, never static) */
}


/* CSS for specific objects */

div#el1 {
  /* any positioning and dimensioning properties for element 1 should go here */
  left: 100px;
  top: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div#el2 {
  /* any positioning and dimensioning properties for element 2 should go here */
  left: 400px;
  top: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div#el1>div.object {
  /* all other properties for element 1 should go here */
  background-color: purple;
}

div#el2>div.object {
  /* all other properties for element 2 should go here */
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="anchor" id="el1">
  <div class="object">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="anchor" id="el2">
  <div class="object">
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially what we're doing is setting up one object to define the position, width and height of the element, and then placing another one inside of it that gets offset by 50%, and gets its parent dimensions (ie `width: 100%`).

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this question, and I'd like to add another way to center content within a div.

By using the CSS3 display mode 'flexible box', as in setting the following CSS properties to the parent div

```
display: flex;
position: relative;
align-items: center;
justify-content:center;
```

And 'at least' setting the following properties to the child div

```
position:relative;
```

The browser will automatically center the contents within the parent div, unaffected by their width or height, this particularly comes in handy when you're developing something like an image grid or just want to remove the hassle of calculating a divs position, then having to recalculate it when you change your mind about the set-up of said div.

In my own work, I tend to set-up a class named

```
.center-center
```

With the properties I described for the parent div, then just add it to whatever element of which I need its contents centered.

I've created a JSFiddle to support this explanation, feel free to click on the red squares to see the positioning in action.

https://jsfiddle.net/f1Lfqrfs/

For multi-line support, you can add (or uncomment in the JSF) the following CSS property to the parent DIV

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

left:50% doesn't center the center of gravity of this div 50% to the left, it is the distance between the left border and the left border of the parent element, so basically you need to do some calculations.

```
left = Width(parent div) - [ Width(child div) + Width(left border) + Width(right border) ]

left = left / 2
```

So you can do a Javascript function...

```
function Position(var parentWidth, var childWith, var borderWidth)
{
      //Example parentWidth = 400, childWidth = 200, borderWidth = 1
      var left = (parentWidth - ( childWidth + borderWidth));
      left = left/2;
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left= left+"px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this would work, but you just denied the only two things I asked for - no need to manually accomodate it for each element's width and no scripting, just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `transform: translateX` with `calc` for horizonally positioning by element center instead of top-left. Same trick can be used for vertical using `transform: transformY`. This will work with width of any type *(try resizing)*

Snippet: `transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 223px));`

Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d, https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Codepen for more examples: https://codepen.io/manikantag/pen/KJpxmN

Note on offsetLeft/offsetTop etc: `el.offsetLeft` will not given proper value for CSS transformed elements. You would require something like `el.getBoundingClientRect().left - el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft` *([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295670/get-divs-position-after-translate3d/28305099?noredirect=1#comment47697241_28305099))*

**Note about flow effect:** as detailed in [CSS Things That Don’t Occupy Space](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-things-that-dont-occupy-space/), transform doesn't effect the following element without considering the offset caused by transform. Sometimes this may not be the intended behavior. This can be fixed using negative margins if width/height are fixed (doesn't work if width/height are using `%`)

```css
.left-positioned {
  margin-left: 223px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.center-positioned {
  transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 223px)); /*=====> actual solution */
  background-color: cyan;
}

.with-width {
  width: 343px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


/* styles not related to actual solution */

div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ele left-positioned">Reference element (left at 223px)</div> <br/>
  <div class="ele center-positioned">^<br/>Center positioned element (center at 223px)</div> <br/>
  <div class="ele center-positioned with-width">^<br/>Center positioned element with width (center at 223px)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move an element so that it's centre is in the same position as it's pointer using the [`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [`translate` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()) like so:

```css
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

which is the equivalent of:

```css
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

This will move the element back half its length across the X and Y axis so its centre will be over the pointer where you place it.

### Centre Example

So for example, if you wanted to place an element in the centre of its parent you would first put the pointer in the centre like so:

```css
left: 50%
top: 50%
```

and then add the transformation to move the centre of the element over the pointer, like so:

```css
left: 50%
top: 50%
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

> Thanks to [Joe Rhoney, 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383937/joe-rhoney) for suggesting the use of `transform` in a previous answer's comment.