# Get divs position after translate3d

Tags: javascript, html, position, translate3d

In Javascript, when I move an element using the gpu via the translate3d method, the elements style-left position doesnt change at all. As the cpu isnt even aware any motion has occurred.

How do I track what the new position of an element is, after moving it via translate3d?

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery, `getBoundingClientRect` can give you the current element position even transformed by CSS3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the element coordinates

Here's just a small example that retrieves the `.left` *Rect* property from a CSS3 translated (animated) element:

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const printer = document.getElementById('printer');
const printBoxRectLeft = () => {
  printer.textContent = box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  requestAnimationFrame(printBoxRectLeft);
};

printBoxRectLeft();
```

```css
#box{
  width:30px; height:30px; background:red;
  animation: animX 3s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animX { to{ transform:translateX(300px); }}
```

```html
<div id="printer"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: smooth solution. never heard of that function.

Comment: THANK YOU. I use this for many things but didn't realize this would end the nightmare of getting things done with translations!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan unfortunately, this only works great with elements that fill the window width, translated elements wrapped inside more other elements show different `getBoundingClientRect` values. Perhaps we should use element's offsetLeft value to adjust?

Comment: I confirm temporarily.. `el.getBoundingClientRect().left - el.offsetLeft` always gives the closest value to actual translate value.

Comment: When I make a quick test with `el.getBoundingClientRect().left - el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft ` this gets even more accurate with a more complex structure.

Comment: @thednp yes, GBCR gives the position relative to the client window, means if you need to get a position *relative* to some other element subtraction needs to be done.

Comment: @thednp any idea when we might need to include `el.offsetLeft` in `el.getBoundingClientRect().left - el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft` ?

Comment: @manikanta out the back of my neck... you'd perhaps need to include other variables when you're not strictly interested in the position relative to the viewport, but relative to a scrollable parent element...

Answer (score 3):

The style attribute left is set to auto if you do not set it manually. But you should be able to use the jquery function position().

```
    var position = $('#element').position();
    var left = position.left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqab2aw7/2/

Comment: In that fiddle i converted rotateY to translate3d(330px,0,0) and yes.. it does seem to work. So at least there is a way, would be even better if there were a jquery-free one.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers that use `getBoundingClientRect` work in most cases, but it calculates from the viewport, not the DOM's actual 0,0. So if the parent element has negative coords, and is off screen, `getBoundingClientRect` will return the wrong coordinates.

It also ignores `margin`, `padding`, and `borderWidth`, so if you need to be very precise:

`trueLeft = rect.left - margin.left - padding.left - borderWidth - offsetX`

to get the other values could use a `RegExp`:

```
'translate3d(256px, 512px, 0px)'.replace(/translate3d|px|\(|\)/gi, '').split(',');

// { x: trueLeft, y: translate3d[1], z: translate3d[2] }
```